# Pandas write CSV file with custome dilimiteer value in single dataRow

Tags: python, pandas

I have requirement where my column in fixed but for last dol (data) value is delimited like this "~"
example: data: "a1~b1~c1~" when in print csv if is using

example code :

```
import pandas as pd 
temp="~".join(["amit1","amit2","amit3","amit4"])
df_cols = ["Record Type", "version", "data"]
df_rows = [{"Record Type":110002,"version":111.000,"data":temp +"~"}]
out_df=pd.DataFrame(df_rows, columns = df_cols)
print(out_df)
out_df.to_csv('fileName',sep='~',index=False,quotechar=" " )
```

and output csv  is adding space in the data column 
Record  Type ~version~data
110002~111.0~ amit1~amit2~amit3~amit4~         //from this row I don't want any space before **amit1**

I wanted to remove extra space from data column values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The added spaces are there due to your use of `quotechar=" "` and the fact that `Record Type` has a space in it. `to_csv` closes `Record Type` off with the given `quotechar`, namely a space.

What are you trying to achieve with using that specific `quotechar`? Do you really need it?

```
import pandas as pd 
data_col = "~".join(["amit1","amit2","amit3","amit4"]) + "~"
pd.DataFrame({"Record Type": 110002, "version": 111.000, "data": data_col}, [0])
df_out.to_csv('fileName.csv',sep='~',index=False)
```

P.s. note that if supplying `pd.DataFrame()` with a dictionary, you don't need to give it the column names as well.

Answer (score 0):

thank for the response. 
Following use case which I am trying to achieve if I don't use -- quotechar=" "  then the output will be like this.

Record Type~version~data
110002~111.0~**"amit1~amit2~amit3~amit4~"**   - see "I don't want quotes before and after the string" - I am creating data: "a1~b1~c~" -- here my joining and separator both are same.

I am forming data value with multiple dynamic inputs so my data columns value is not fixed. 
I am getting array object - (this is single data value -  "~".join(["amit1","amit2","amit3","amit4"]) + "~)

thanks